# Jquery calling get method of spring controller in place of post

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I am trying to call a post method of my Spring MVC controller using POST method and here is the method of my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("springSecurity/login.json")
public class SpringSecurityLoginController
{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public SpringSecurityLoginStatus getStatus()
        {
            return springSecurityLoginService.getStatus();
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public SpringSecurityLoginStatus login(@RequestParam("j_username") final String username,
                @RequestParam("j_password") final String password, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        {

            LOG.info("Starting login process");
            return springSecurityLoginService.login(username, password, request, response);
        }
}
```

### HTML

```
<form:form action="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" class="login-form " id="loginForm"  method="post" commandName="loginForm">

<form:input path="j_username" class="text" id="login_id" value="" name ="j_username"/>
<form:password path="j_password" class="text" value="Password" name="j_password" id="j_password"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="LOGIN" id="login" />
</form:form>
```

and here is my Jquery code

```
jQuery("#login").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery.ajax({url: getHost() + "${request.contextPath}/springSecurity/login.json",
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
            },
            data: jQuery("#loginForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data, status) {
                if (data.loggedIn) {
                   // location.href = getHost() + '${ctx}/users';
                    //login_pannel

                } else {
                    loginFailed(data);
                }
            },
            error: loginFailed
        });
    });
```

But the above code is calling

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public SpringSecurityLoginStatus getStatus()
```

and not

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public SpringSecurityLoginStatus login(@RequestParam("j_username") final String username,
@RequestParam("j_password") final String password, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
```

i am not sure why this behavior is occuring

Comment: What is the request mapping? can you post that also.

Comment: Just trying to weed out stuff: What does the HTML of the form look like?  Why are you using live() instead of on() or bind() or delegate()?

Comment: @subirkumarsao: i have added request mapping

Comment: @fisherwebdev: i have included the HTML and being new to Jquery even i am not sure why live(), i just saw some example and trying that

Comment: Try examining the request in Chrome Developer Tools or a similiar tool, to determine whether the problem is client-side or server-side. In Chrome Dev Tools, you would be looking at the Network tab.  That will tell you whether the browser is sending a POST or a GET.

Comment: @fisherwebdev: i tied using firefox bugzila and its sending both get and post request. for get request its getting `200` while for POST its getting `302` i am not sure why this is happening

Comment: Are you doing a redirect after the POST, which is a GET?

Comment: @fisherwebdev: i am not doing any redirect, still will check it and update

Comment: @fisherwebdev:i tested it and your assumption is correct. i am sending request to following URL `https://localhost:9002/myapp/springSecurity/login.json` and browser response header showing location as `http://localhost:9001/myapp/springSecurity/login.json` this means https has been changed to http as well the port.i am not sure how to handle this as from my Spring-MVC i am returning `JSON` data

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/springSecurity")

public class SpringSecurityLoginController
{

    @RequestMapping(value="/login.json",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public SpringSecurityLoginStatus getStatus()
        {
            return springSecurityLoginService.getStatus();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/login.json",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public SpringSecurityLoginStatus login(@RequestParam("j_username") final String username,
                @RequestParam("j_password") final String password, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        {

            LOG.info("Starting login process");
            return springSecurityLoginService.login(username, password, request, response);
        }
}
```

Make this small change and try.

Comment: As per the question both the method maps to the same url but differs on the request method. You are changing the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using server side code that has been designed for a normal HTTP POST, followed by a redirect GET upon success.

If you want to do Ajax (and doing Ajax for user login is a very dangerous situation, not to be taken lightly), then you want to be returning something more appropriate, like JSON, and not do the redirect.

In Firebug for Firefox, in the Net tab, open up that 302 response and look at the response headers.  I bet you'll find there is a Location header there that is telling the browser to redirect.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am using JSON as a mode of data communication, will test what you have suggested and will update the post about the outcome

Comment: i tested it and your assumption is correct. i am sending request to following URL `https://localhost:9002/myapp/springSecurity/login.json` and browser response header showing location as `http://localhost:9001/myapp/springSecurity/login.json` this means https has been changed to http as well the port.i am not sure how to handle this as from my Spring-MVC i am returning `JSON` data

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with the details of Spring MVC.  I'm more of a JavaScript and Ruby person.  But I think we've identified the root of the problem -- the Location header in the response.  I'm sure that's a solvable problem.

Comment: But one more thing: You should probably specify the data type you are expecting to receive, rather than relying on jQuery to guess that the data is JSON.

Comment: i already corrected that by specifying data type as json, still issue is same :(